# Why do I get function undefined error from html doc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I have written a small chat app. 
At first, all the code was contained in the one HTML document, and worked ok.
After seperating the CSS, HTML, and JS into seperate files.
The function, register_popup, invoked from within the HTML doc, now gererates;

```
"ReferenceError: register_popup is not defined"
```

I can see that the script is loading and from the developer tools I see no issues, all 200's and 302's.

THE HTML

```
<div class="sidebar-name">
            <a href="#" onclick="register_popup('user4', 

'USER4');">

                <img width="30" height="30" src="" />
                <span>user4</span>
            </a>
```

script can be seen loading...
Am using,

```
<script>
var url = "static/js/chatpop.js";
$.getScript(url);
</script>
```

Have alos tried changing the HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar-name">
            <a href="javascript:register_popup('user3', 'USER3');">
                <img width="30" height="30" src="" />
                <span>user3</span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

but that does not work either. As mentioned, I get a 200 on loading the script, and when contained in the same page everything worked. Only after separating the code into respective files does the error happen,

The following can also be seen loading ok.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3      /jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Any help welcome ...

The Function

```
function register_popup(id, name)
            {

                for(var iii = 0; iii < popups.length; iii++)
                {  
                    //already registered. Bring it to front.
                    if(id == popups[iii])
                    {
                        Array.remove(popups, iii);

                        popups.unshift(id);

                        calculate_popups();


                        return;
                    }
                }              

                var element = '<div class="popup-box chat-popup" id="'+ id +'">';
                element = element + '<div class="popup-head">';
                element = element + '<div class="popup-head-left">'+ name +'</div>';
                element = element + '<div class="popup-head-right"><a href="javascript:close_popup(\''+ id +'\');">&#10005;</a></div>';
                element = element + '<div style="clear: both"></div></\
                div><div class="popup-messages">\
                <form action="chatpop/post" id="chat-form" method="post">\
                <textarea style="resize:none;"cols="41" rows="14" >\
                </textarea><input type="submit" id="chat-form" value="Send">\
                </input></form></div></div>';

                document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML + element; 

                popups.unshift(id);

                calculate_popups();

            }
```

Comment: The script loads but does it load before you attempt to call the function?

Comment: Yes it does ...

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
<script>
  var url = "static/js/chatpop.js";
  $.getScript(url);
</script>
```

You're attempting to import the script in an asynchronous way and invoke some functions defined in the script immediately in your html (before the script is actually loaded).

You should either refer your script in the header in a blocking manner like:

```
<script src="static/js/chatpop.js" />
```

or changing your anchor tag once the script is fetched:

```
...
<a id="myAnchor">
...

$.getScript(url).done(function(){
        $("#myAnchor").attr("href", register_popup('user3', 'USER3'))
    });
}
```

Comment: Why do I see a 200 GET chatpop.js_"CSRF_VALUE" ...also if I invoke getScript as you suggest it would only work for the referenced user and not others??

Comment: yes, 200 means the script is loaded correctly, the problem is that you're doing it asynchronously and you're trying to invoke the functions in your HTML before the script is actually available

Comment: thks for the help... But the 1st suggestion results in blank page, i.e the blocking method . The second gives me SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' .Which is refering to the DOCTYPE statement, and after clicking on the user, it generates " ReferenceError: register_popup is not defined", and also,  "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' "